# Makefile misses a rule which looks to be available

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile

I have the following Makefile which I want to use to build a project `serial.c` in Linux which lies in the current directory, but which uses C++ libraries from inside `src` and `include`, which should be build into a directory `obj`, keeping all the files clear and separated.

```
#define some paths
DHOME      = ${HOME}/Serial
SRC        = ${DHOME}/src
INCLUDE    = ${DHOME}/include
BIN        = ${DHOME}/bin
OBJ        = ${DHOME}/obj

# compiler
CFLAGS        = -I$(INCLUDE)
CXX           = g++ -g ${INCLUDE} 
MAKE          = ${CXX} -O -Wall -fPIC -c

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cc
    $(MAKE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o ${OBJ}/$@ 

serial: $(OBJ)/%.o
    ${CXX} -o $@ $@.c $< $(CFLAGS) 


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -f serial $(OBJ)/*.o
```

The error message when trying `make serial` or just `make` is

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/alex/Serial/obj/%.o', needed by `serial'.  Stop.
```

But when looking at the Makefile it seem I have specified this rule (the rule above the `serial` rule). I probably missed something basical. Maybe there is a better way to handle such a project and to have the different pieces clearly separated in directories?

Thanks, 
  Alex

Comment: Have a look at pattern matching rules for make and check your rules again. The hint is that make tries to interpret `%.o` as an actual file name. Further, never ever overload names like `MAKE` in your makefile. This is to ask for trouble. Even further, separate flags from commands and put the `-O -Wall -fPIC -c` bit in `CXXFLAGS` where it belongs.

Comment: Looking at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html I seem to do everything correct! Maybe I overlook something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your rule:

```
serial: $(OBJ)/%.o
```

Since there is no `%` in the TARGET of this rule, this is not a pattern rule.  So it looks for a file named `/home/alex/Serial/obj/%.o` (literally) which doesn't exist and can't be made.

You need to have `serial` depend on a list of actual object file names.  Then the pattern rule  `$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cc` can match each of those and will be used to compile it.

**edit**

If you want to generate that list automatically, you can use a glob rule on your sourcefiles, and then a pattern replacement to generate the object files:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cc)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SRC)/%.cc=$(OBJ)/%.o)
```

Comment: I tried to create a list of source files; instead of using `c_files = $(SRC)/Serial.cpp` (this worked very good) I tried `c_files = $(wildcard $(SRC)/%.cpp)` (which did not work at all). I expected the exact same content.

Comment: @Alex There should be `c_files = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)`, you're confusing make patterns with shell globs.

Comment: @Eldar Finally! Please put this and the other things above to get you a correct answer...

Comment: @Alex, my answer wouldn't differ too much, so please feel free to accept this one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching rules act on *targets*.

You do not supply a list of targets to be built so the pattern matching does not work as you assume it does.

Pattern matching is *not* constructed to work as a wildcard on the command line. You can not ask make to look for targets, you have to supply them.

So, if `serial` depends on some specific `.o` files, you need to supply these. The easiest way to do that is to rewrite your rule:

```
serial: $(OBJ)/foo.o $(OBJ)/bar.o $(OBJ)/fie.o
    #Insert build command here, as needed
```

This will trigger the pattern matching as each object file is set as a target before `serial` can be linked.

Comment: This seems to work, but I wanted to avoid to list all the object files. Suppose I have 100 of object files I need to link? This would be very circumstantial! I want to provide a list of objects automatically, say, from the list of cc files in the SRC directory. Isn't this the whole goal of having a makefile? Otherwise I can type each gcc command on the commad line...

Comment: @Alex As EldarAbusalimov writes in his comment, you are confusing two concepts. I answered your question about why your makefile does not do what you expect. To have make generate a list of files _to be used as prerequisits_ in a build rule is something else.